# ASP.Net MVC4, jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page where I need to show/hide divs based on what button the user clicks. In the page, I have two divs (divBranchList and divGrowerList) and two buttons (btnBranch and btnGrower). I am using the following code to show/hide the divs.

```
      $(document).bind('pageinit', function () {
        alert("here");
        $("#divBranchList").hide();

        //show hide lists
        $("#btnGrower").click(function () {

         $("#divGrowerList").show();
         $("#divBranchList").hide();
       });

      $("#btnBranch").click(function () {
          $("#divBranchList").show();
          $("#divGrowerList").hide();
       });

      });
```

While this works perfectly when the page loads or if I refresh the page, but fails to work when the user clicks on a listitem and the page comes back from the server after getting some data. The page has both lists visible although if I put a breakpoint at the following line in Firebug's script panel, it does get hit.

```
    $("#divBranchList").hide();
```

Any ideas why the div is not hiding or how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're showing and hiding content in a JQueryMobile page, you will probably need to trigger the [UpdateLayout](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) event

```
$("#divBranchList").trigger("updatelayout");
```

after you've done your showing / hiding...